Lombok classes not generated
I’m using Intellij IDEA Community Edition (the latest version: Build #IC-242.23339.11, built on September 25, 2024)
here is my build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnit()
} 

gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists 

entity class:
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Test {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int yearOfBirth;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String secondaryPhoneNumber;
    private LocalDate createdAt;
} 

the java version is: 17.0.12
I’m not doing anything crazy. I just need Lombok to properly generate the Builder class for me but whenever i run
.\gradlew clean build

or
.\gradlew compileJava

then nothing is being generated in build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main
marking “Enable annotation processing” as checked in the IDEA settings doesnt resolve this issue
I also tried to play with different lombok and gradle versions but the issue is still there
Invalidating caches did not help either
What am i missing? I’d appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Maybe, the IDE not add lombok to classpath, you need to do it manually.

As stated on the lombok setup page for IntelliJ the plugin needs to be added to the IDE for versions after 2023.1.

Thank you! seems like this was exactly the issue, i'm marking your answer as the right one

I've created the similar project and found the Test.class file in the path similar to build/classes/java/main/org/example/.../Test.class
You can also use the RMB (Context menu) -> Refactor -> Delombok
